# Woocommerce after checkout redirection if order items belongs to specific product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I need to make it so when people press place order on our webshop, they will get redirectet to My Account, but only if the categories is XXX , XXX , XXX

But i can't seem to get it working unfortunally

I have tried using `&& is_product_category('Category x','Category x','Category x')`

```
// REDIRECT AFTER PLACE ORDER BUTTON!
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'KSVS_redirect_custom');
function KSVS_redirect_custom( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $url = 'https://kanselvvilselv.dk/min-konto/';

    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

It is working without putting in `&& is_product_category('Category x','Category x','Category x')`, But then it is working on categories where it should not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code using dedicated `template_redirect` hook and WordPress [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function *(to be used with product categories)*, will redirect customers after checkout to my account section, when their order contain items from defined product categories:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'order_received_redirection_to_my_account' );
function order_received_redirection_to_my_account() {
    // Only on "Order received" page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        global $wp;

        // HERE below define your product categories in the array
        $categories = array('Tshirts', 'Hoodies', 'Glasses');

        $order = wc_get_order( absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ); // Get the Order Object
        $category_found = false;

        // Loop theough order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                $category_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( $category_found ) {
            // My account redirection url
            $my_account_redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
            wp_redirect( $my_account_redirect_url );
            exit(); // Always exit
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Updated, this should loop through all ordered products and if it matches 1 product with a category then it will redirect to your URL:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'KSVS_redirectcustom');

function KSVS_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
    $url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );

    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {

        $product_cats = array('product-cat1', 'product-cat', 'product-cat3');

        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {

            if ( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product->id) ) {
                $cat_check = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $cat_check ) {
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using a singular is_product_category() without the || for the extra 2 and see if that works. They are ordering from a category page right? Not a checkout page?

Comment: No, it is after the final checkout when they press Place Order - Then they need to be redirectet to my account page, but it is only for some of the categories :)

Comment: Oh right, no wonder then is_product_category() checks if the page is currently a product category, you'll need to loop through all items purchased to check if they are in one of the categories if so then redirect. If the other guys answer doesn't fix it then I will have a go

Answer (score 0):

Note: i'm not familiar with woocommerce at all, please take my answer with ease.
Seems like function `is_product_category` have different purpouse, by quick overview I came with this, give it a try:

```
$redirectWhenCategoryIs = ['cat x', 'cat y', 'cat z'];

$categories = [];
foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
    foreach(get_the_terms($item['product_id'], 'product_cat') as $term){
        $categories[] = $term->slug;
    }
}

if(count(array_intersect($redirectWhenCategoryIs, $categories))){
    wp_redirect($url);
}
```